# What are the XP levels for units in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there a table or formula to specify what the XP "steps" are for units in Civilization 5?

For example, if a unit will receive +30 XP from military buildings, how can I tell what level it will be?

Comment: I believe the first two levels are at +15 and +30, but beyond that I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The promotion costs for the next level can can be calculated by Previous level XP + (10 * Next level)

- So for level 1 :  0 + (10 * 1) = 10
- Level 2 : 10 + (10 * 2) = 30
- Level 3 : 30 + (10 * 3) = 60
- Level 4 : 60 + (10 * 4) = 100

And so on.

Source : [Civ fanatics forum](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=458845)

Comment: This will mean, that level n requires 5*n*(n+1) xp and x xp will get you to level floor( sqrt( x/5 ) ).